# Can't SSH as root into EC2 server - Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, root

I am trying to SSH into my server via WinSCP, although the problem will occur with putty as well.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 I have edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added `PermitRootLogin without-password` to the bottom of the file. But this still doesn't seem to have changed my problem.

People have mentioned needed to restart ssh demon. I have tried:

```
 /etc/init.d/sshd reload
 reload sshd.service
 /etc/init.d/sshd reload
```

All of the above are unrecognised.

I have then tried `Files ¬ Custom Commands ¬ sudo -s & su` No luck there either.

Comment: This is a problem for *da-da-da-dah!* superuser(.com)!

Comment: using private keys ;)

Comment: @statueuphemism I thought so, but i saw another problem almost identical on here... :O

Comment: Okay with keys no topic. Do you have a line like `AllowUsers ububtu`

Comment: inside of sshd_config? no i don't

Comment: @statueuphemism: ironically, I think it would be more suited to ServerFault (but anyway, it [would be a duplicate there](http://serverfault.com/questions/216174/how-ubuntu-cloud-version-enforces-the-no-root-login-over-ssh)).

Comment: @nneonneo I guess the definitions of SuperUser and ServerFault could use a little better definition in that case since SuperUser is for the enthusiast and ServerFault is for professionals and system admins per the StackExchange descriptions (I personally don't know any admins who would allow root login without a password). Defintely a good find though.

Comment: they certainly good be :(

Comment: I personally think that the number of views on this question means that it should be reopened.

Comment: Above comments deriding the user for root login without a password indicate lack of knowledge of OpenSSH; "without-password" really means "forbid password authentication, but other mechanisms will work" and typically means that pubkey auth must be used.

Comment: For anyone still looking: this string comes from cloud-init, which defaults to disabling the root user. Set false the `disable_root` option passed to cloud-init to inhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

http://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync describes all the options available to you, and includes instructions for enabling SSH to root on EC2:

```
ssh -i KEYPAIR.pem ubuntu@HOSTNAME   'sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'
```

Comment: For the record, current Ubuntu 14.04 LTS AMI's have the same authorized_keys in /root/.ssh and /home/ubuntu.  However, trying to log in with root yields ```Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".```  I haven't found how they're doing that yet.

Comment: Simple: ssh sends the username as part of the auth process, so the user's profile or shell can determine what you see.

Comment: Yep, but it's not ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile doing it...  Nor is it limited by ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or ForceCommand in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Check `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` :)

Comment: Not there either.  Nor /root/.bashrc etc.

Comment: @nneonneo Wow, I didn't know such options were available per-key. (I was just looking for howto enable root-login in centos 7 cloud image)

Comment: @GregBell Look in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` you can disable it there.

Comment: @EricdesCourtis already addressed that above... wasn't in there.

Comment: My ubuntu-based AMI has this line in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` - `no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa key-goes-here`

Comment: Just remove everything from `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and leave only the ssh key.