# Root login Ubuntu VM on Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure

Installed Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 from Azure library on Azure VM.
Logged in as standard "azureuser" created by Azure with my password.
Changed root password:

```
sudo passwd root
```

If I try to login as "root":

```
Access denied
```

What do I miss?
And yes, the password is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

by default, Ubuntu disables the root account.  Since root is godmode, disabling it means that all of the hackers with automated scripts that try to break the root account are wasting their time.

**I highly recommend against this.**  (There are many reasons, here are some: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root)  However, the steps to do so are [Over on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

According to that page, to unlock the root account you must execute `sudo passwd -u root`.  To relock the root account, use `sudo passwd -l root`

To reiterate: this is kinda a bad idea.  A better solution would be to create a new user that has unlimited permissions ONLY WITHIN THE SCOPE OF WHAT YOU REQUIRE.  Root is godmode; if you screw something up too bad for you.  An elevated user for your scope, on the other hand, would only be able to destroy what it has access to...not your entire system.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. And just setting password worked fine on non-Azure VM.

Comment: @RussellUhl, so what do I do if I want to run `apt-get install ...` and get `Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), are you root?`

Comment: @eddyP23 ARE you root?  my answer is how to unlock the root account.  Just because you ran that doesn't mean you're running AS root at that point

Comment: Sorry, my confusion here is that you are saying it is bad to `sudo -` and then run commands. So my question here was, how is `sudo <cmd>` better than actually becoming root and running the same `<cmd>`

Comment: I understand that running applications as root is bad and you need to be extra careful, but I sometimes you just have to become root to run some commands. Sorry, I think I got my head around the issue now.

Comment: @eddyP23 OH!  Yes, of course running some commands as root is sometimes necessary.  But it is usually better to sudo them rather than actually logging into the root user space and running from there

Answer (score 67):

Just run `sudo -s`, you will get the root terminal.

Comment: Yup this is what I was looking for as I didnt want to login technically but use the root prompt

Comment: I installed debian 9 on azure and sudo -s worked for me

Answer (score 8):

To enter into a Azure VM using SSH...

First,
You need to enable the root account:

```
#sudo passwd root
```

Then you need to enable the root login for ssh editing the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config (the default value in Azure VMs is PermitRootLogin without-password, so you need to change/comment it):

```
...
#PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitRootLogin yes
...
```

Finally, you need to reload/restart the ssh service:

```
#sudo service ssh reload
```

Comment: But as @Russell Uhl explained, this is not a good practice. So, once you do whatever you want, disable the root account again.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 you also need to overwrite /root/.ssh/authorized_keys with your own public key otherwise you will get a 'please login as user xxx' message

Answer (score 1):

It's easier just to do `sudo <command>`. Then you don't have the full terminal for the super user. This will just execute the command with root privileges. 
See [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges/).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but it happens sometimes. Here is what I solved after research.

sample log

```
$ azure vm extension set hm hm  CustomScript Microsoft.Azure.Extensions 2.0 --auto-upgrade-minor-version  -i '{"commandToExecute": "cp /tmp/sudoers.org /etc/sudoers"}' info:    Executing command vm extension set
+ Looking up the VM "hm"
+ Installing extension "CustomScript", VM: "hm" info:    vm extension set command OK
```

For macOS user, here is simple steps. (at least you need node installed)

```
npm install -g azure-cli
azure login
azure config mode arm
```

or asm, depends on your VM

```
azure vm list
```

change mode if no VM listed

copy sudoers file from other machine to /tmp/sudoers.default of you target machine

backup sudoers

```
azure vm extension set hm hm  CustomScript Microsoft.Azure.Extensions 2.0 --auto-upgrade-minor-version  -i '{"commandToExecute": "cp /etc/sudoers /tmp"}'
```

copy default sudoers to /etc/sudoers

```
azure vm extension set hm hm  CustomScript Microsoft.Azure.Extensions 2.0 --auto-upgrade-minor-version  -i '{"commandToExecute": "cp /tmp/sudoers.default /etc/sudoers"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get any of the other answers to work for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722886/cant-ssh-as-root-into-ec2-server-please-login-as-the-user-ubuntu-rather-tha) answer worked for my case.

For those too lazy to click the link:

```
ssh -i KEYPAIR.pem ubuntu@HOSTNAME   'sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'
```