# Running shipit-deploy as sudo on remote Azure VM

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, web-deployment

I need to deploy several NodeJS applications to Ubuntu 14.04.4 Virtual Machines running on Microsoft Azure.
I am using [shipit](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) with [shipit-deploy](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit-deploy) for the task.

My `shipitfile.js` so far looks like the following:

```
module.exports = function (shipit) {
  require('shipit-deploy')(shipit);

  var stagingConfig = require('./config.staging').deploy;
  var productionConfig = require('./config.prod').deploy;

  shipit.initConfig({
    default: {
      workspace: '/tmp/my-api',
      deployTo: '/var/www/my-api',
      repositoryUrl: 'https://githubrepoaddresshere.git',
      ignores: ['.git', 'node_modules', 'migrations', 'dumpDB', 'logs', 'bin'],
      rsync: ['--del'],
      keepReleases: 2,
      key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem',
      shallowClone: true
    },
    staging: stagingConfig,
    production: productionConfig
  });

  shipit.on('init', function() {
    console.log('Starting deployment...');
  });

  shipit.on('deployed', function () {
    // npm install etc etc
  });
};
```

The `stagingConfig` variable is an object holding environment specific information:

```
{
  "branch": "develop",
  "servers": "username@my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
}
```

When I run `shipit staging deploy` command, I get

```
'deploy:update' errored after 3.41 s
Error: Command failed: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem "username@my-api-staging.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" "mkdir -p /var/www/my-api/releases/20160429125114"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/my-api/releases’: Permission denied
```

I know I could either:

1) Try to deploy on `/home/username` 
2) [Use this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376298/4508762) to start the ssh session as `root`.

I still have to try the first and not willing to use the second for sure.

So my question is: is there a clean and non hacky solution to make `shipit-deploy` prefix each and every command it runs during deployment with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify the variable [`shipit.releasesPath`](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit-deploy#shipitreleasepath) to your home path which do not need `sudo` prefix in commands.

So your deployment task doesn't need the administrator permission, which will also avoid some unanticipated permission operation issues.

E.G.

```
shipit.initConfig({
    default: {
      ...
    },
    staging: {
      servers: '<user>@<your_vm_name>.cloudapp.net'
    }
  });
  shipit.releasesPath = '/home/www/releases';
```